# FindMinimum where variables are Integers

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I wish to find the minimum of a function where the variables are integers. Here is a simple minimum working example (my actual function is much more complicated).

```
ClearAll[f];
f[{i1_, i2_}] := N[Total[1 + Sin[#] & /@ {i1, i2}]];


FindMinimum[{f[{i1, i2}], 
  0 < i1 < 11 && 10 < i2 < 21 && {i1, i2} \[Element] Integers}, {{i1, 
   5}, {i2, 15}}]
```

The result is an error message saying integers are only allowed for linear programming.

Is there a technique for solving this sort of problem? Thanks

Comment: Try using `NMinimize` instead, e.g., `NMinimize[{f[{i1, i2}], 
  0 < i1 < 11 && 10 < i2 < 21}, {i1, i2} ∈ Integers]`

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes that works. Thanks,  I should have looked further. Please post if you wish to be accepted.